# Django TestCase check ValidationError with assertRaises in is throwing ValidationError

Tags: python, django, django-tests, validationerror

I have a model where i have overridden save function something like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  number = models.PositiveIngeter()
  def save(self,*args, **kwargs)
    if self.number > 10:
      super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
      raise ValidationError('msg')
```

and the function i am testing is like

```
def test_number(self):
  myModel = MyModel(number=5)
  self.assertRaises(ValidationError,myModel.save)

the error i got is like this:
ERROR: test_number(apps.players.tests.test_models.CityDetailTestCase)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sagar/project/apps/players/tests/test_models.py", line 740, in test_number
    self.asserttRaises(ValidationError,mumbai.save)
  File "/home/sagar/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 733, in assertRaises
    return context.handle('assertRaises', args, kwargs)
  File "/home/sagar/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 178, in handle
    callable_obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sagar/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/sagar/project/apps/players/models.py", line 2452, in save
    raise ValidationError("msg")
rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: ['msg']
```

I'm new to Django and unable to figure out what's wrong with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call the method, simply pass it as a parameter:

```py
from django.test import TestCase

class MyModelTest(TestCase):
   def test_my_model(self):
      myModel = MyModel(number=5)
      self.asserRaises(ValidationError, myModel.save)
```

Comment: Still got the error can you check the error now

Comment: @SagarGupta Have you used a TestCase? I've edited my answer

Comment: @SagarGupta Check if you made writing errors in your original code, try to share it

Comment: Got it. It was an import issue i had this at models.py from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError and i needed this from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError.I didn't checked for this before